# Creating a 2dimentional table in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, collections

I am facing a problem that confuses me. 
In Java, I am reading a CSV file that looks like this (albeit much longer):

```
Task | Assignee
1    | A
2    | A
3    | B
4    | B
5    | C
```

Using [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net), I have stored Assignees as a HashSet as I want to have a set that represents all my assignees without duplicates. And I have stored the Tasks as an ArrayList. 
Now, I want to make a table out of this so that:

```
Assignee | Task
A        | 1, 2
B        | 3, 4
C        | 5
```

What would be the best way to go about this so that I can look up what Tasks belong to a selected assignee?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Map<Assignee, List<Task>>

Comment: I was thinking something along 
List<List<String>> assignment = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

assignment.add(Assignee);
for(String a : Task){
....
}

But then I do not know how to match a task to the assignee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am really confused with your description.

> I have stored Assignees as a HashSet as I want to have a set that represents all my assignees without duplicates.

Ok, that means you have a `HashSet` that contains `{ A, B, C }`

> And I have stored the Tasks as an ArrayList.

So you have an `ArrayList` that contains `{ 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5 }`.
If i have understood correctly, I have to point out that this approach won't lead you anywhere because you destroyed the mapping between your tasks and assignees.
I whould suggest another approach on this. Use `HashMap<String, List<String>>` with the Assignee as `Key` and a List of Tasks as `Value`.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> taskBook = new HashMap<>();

// read from your csv File a new Line as array containing [ task, asssignee ]
// String[] line = csvReader.read ...    
// and add it to taskBook like this:

String task = line[0];      
String assignee = line[1];

if(taskBook.containsKey(assignee)){
    List<String> taskList = taskBook.get(assignee);
    taskList.add(task);
} else {
    List<String> taskList = new ArrayList<String>();
    taskList.add(task);
    taskBook.put( assignee, taskList );
}

[...]

// then you can get all tasks of an assignee like this:
List<String> tasksOf_A = taskBook.get("A");
```

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation! That does exactly what I need.